# Can I have a function to check if a key is in a map?

Tags: dictionary, go

I want to have a function like `Map.containsKey()` in Go, since Go itself does not provide this kind of functionality, can I alternatively have a custom function like `MapContainsKey(someMap map[K]V, key K)` in Go?

I do not know how to realize it because as far as I know there is no generics in Go yet.

I know I can do

```
if val, ok := someMap[key]; ok{
   // some code here
}
```

but I want to wrap it in a function.

Comment: You can write "standalone" function, or you can attach it to type as a method, like here: https://play.golang.org/p/6a5bX6MLdve

Comment: "I want to wrap it in a function" -- Why? What is the core problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Go will probably have parametric polymorphism (what you would call generics) sometime soon. There is a preliminary "precompiler" that supports this that comes with the compiler called `go2go`, though it may change before it is officially released.  I have tried it to do exactly what you mention.

Comment: @AJR: By "sometime soon", I trust you mean "Possibly in 18-24 months, and in Go 2"?

Comment: @Flimzy like I want to realize `if len(someArray) > 1 && someMap.contains(someArray[1])`, I have to make sure `someArray` have that value of index `1` before I check if that value exists in `someMap`. I cannot do this in if statement `if len(someArray) > 1 && (_, ok := someMap[someArray[1]]; ok)`

Comment: Yes, you need a compound if statement. That's much more lightweight than a function, though. It's also much more clear what's happening in the code (which is one of the main reasons Go takes the philosophy of not hiding complexity like this).

Answer (score 7):

As of Go 1.18, you could create a generic function.

```
func containsKey[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](m M, k K) bool {
  _, ok := m[k]
  return ok
}
```

Example testing it:

```
m1 := map[string]int{"one": 1, "x": 0}
fmt.Println(containsKey(m1, "one"))
fmt.Println(containsKey(m1, "x"))
fmt.Println(containsKey(m1, "two"))

m2 := map[int]string{1: "one", 9: ""}
fmt.Println(containsKey(m2, 1))
fmt.Println(containsKey(m2, 9))
fmt.Println(containsKey(m2, 2))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/KTR8wprCj-W)):

```
true
true
false
true
true
false
```

Comment: Very cool! Stolen. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you said there is this solution :

```
if _, ok := aMap[key]; ok {
  // bla bla bla
}
```

If you want to wrap it in a function, then make this function :

```
type (
    myMap1 map[int]string
    myMap2 map[string]string
)

func (m myMap1) Contains(k int) (ok bool) {
    _, ok = m[k]
    return
}

func (m myMap2) Contains(k string) (ok bool) {
    _, ok = m[k]
    return
}

func main() {
    m1 := make(myMap1)
    m2 := make(myMap2)

    m1[10] = "Hello"

    m2["Hi"] = "こんにちは"

    fmt.Println(m1.Contains(9))  // false
    fmt.Println(m1.Contains(10)) // true

    fmt.Println(m2.Contains("Hello")) // false
    fmt.Println(m2.Contains("Hi"))    // true
}
```

I hope this answers your question